# Every time I start debugger for Unity in Visual Studio Mac, it almost immediately stops

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-mac

The debugging options are greyed out and only default is selected. I have the plugin installed. What else can I do?

[image]

I don't see a unity editor option. I can go to Attach to process and click Unity Debugger and I get a generic error.

Comment: screen shots will help

Comment: Any error messages? Did you install anything different recently? Has it ever worked? OS? We need some more information.

Comment: Ok, attach to process just worked, but I am not sure I changed anything. Still can't start the debugger by pressing run. This is a new computer, and no, it has never worked. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If it is helpful to anyone, I think I installed Visual Studio Code with he Unity Debugger to get the attach to process to work. Would still want to get it to work on run.